# Blender 3.0 Geometry Nodes: Rotate instance to face Normals

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I'm using Blender 3.0Beta, I want to align instances rotation along with the source mesh normals, I've seen people using align rotation to vector node, but it's been removed.

[image]

How do I make it so the instances(the planes) rotate along the normals?
[image]

Comment: do you mean face normals or vertex normals?

Comment: Part of [this updated answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/235776/35559) may answer this question for you

Comment: @lemon my bad, forgot to mention face normals.

Comment: @RobinBetts That also works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use this node setup, here the source geometry was a torus, instance object is a plane.

[image]

here a simple cube with a plane:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! with this as a base, I found what I was looking for.

Comment: not working anymore ? (Blender 4)

Comment: @gordie: sorry, i cannot update all my answer here in BSE for all Blender versions. If you wanna know how that works for newer versions, pls aks a new question. You can open as many questions as you want. thx.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method listed above to set the instances on vertices normal, if you want to set instances on face normal use the setup below.

[image]

[image]